# Difference between logarithm in numpy and theano.tensor

Tags: python, numpy, theano

What is the difference between numpy.log and theano.tensor.log?
Do they perform the same?

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that `numpy.log` will be faster. You can compare them both on your CPU and your data.

```
import theano
import theano.tensor as T
import numpy as 

x = T.vector('x')
theano_log = theano.function([x], T.log(x))

a = np.random.rand(1000).astype(np.float32)  # test data
assert np.allclose(theano_log(a), np.log(a)) # optional correctness check
```

Then measure with:

```
In [6]: %timeit np.log(a)
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.89 µs per loop

In [7]: %timeit theano_log(a)
10000 loops, best of 3: 44.1 µs per loop
```

So for a vector of size 1000 `numpy` is about 5 times faster. This results might vary if you switch to run the calculations in a GPU which you can do with `theano` and not with `numpy`.

The main difference is the way you use each library. In theano if you want to do several operations to an array (ex: log->square->mean) you would declare first a computation graph and then evaluate the whole graph at once which might result in some optimizations. With `numpy` you would evaluate each intermediate step, creating many intermediate variables on the process that can in some cases be avoided in `theano`.